# Android 4 (Nexus) does not connect to Jetty https

Tags: android, https, jetty, certificate

We're running a Jetty 7.6.1 on https://loyalpunch.com with a certificate issued by AlphaSSL. The site works fine in Firefox and Chromium, but fails to load on my Nexus. I have checked with

```
openssl s_client -connect loyalpunch.com:443 -showcerts
```

that the intermediate certificate is installed and TLSv1 is supported. And I have not mistyped anything or have network issues. Replacing https with http makes it work immediately. I have also tried both with Wifi and 3G. Any ideas why the stock Android browser tells me 'The connection to the server timed out'?

Comment: That's rather odd.  I can't get it to work on Chrome for Android either.  Says the operation timed out.

Comment: Well, there is something wrong at the server side/certificate, because I get a warning in IE with "Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors." So you have some sort of problem.

Comment: my droid (dolphin browser) says the name of the site does not match the name on the cert

Comment: @chrkad This error is related to an SSL certificate on https://test.acoveo.com/piwik for our piwik tracking stuff. test.acoveo.com on port https is serving a certificate for a different domainname, which is fine, because we do not intend to use piwik over https (nor loyalpunch.com). But this is unrelated as my actual problem are AJAX calls within a phonegap app and there is obviously no piwik involved in that case.